# getActionCommand is undefined

Tags: java, swing, removeall, actionevent

I been using my textbook to build a GUI but one thing has been plaging me. When I try to make a clear button with a removeAll method it does not work at all.  The problem I have been having is the GetActionCommand() is undefined .

```
import acm.graphics.*;
import acm.program.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;

import acm.program.GraphicsProgram;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

public class GUI_Program extends GraphicsProgram{

public void init() {
    setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    add(Cleared, WEST);
    addActionListeners();
    sizeSlider = new JSlider(MIN_SIZE, MAX_SIZE, INITIAL_SIZE);
    add(new JLabel(" small"), WEST);
    add(sizeSlider, WEST);
    add(new JLabel("Large "), WEST);
    ColorBox();

    add(colorBox, WEST);

    addMouseListeners();

}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Clear")) {
        removeAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

`import javafx.event.ActionEvent;`

There is more than one `ActionEvent` class, and this is the wrong one.  Removing this line should fix the error.  (The correct `ActionEvent` will then be imported by the line `import java.awt.event.*;` which you already have in your code.)